# Tool for merging OSM and Google route data

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, merge, google-maps-api

I'm using google API in order to solve a routing problem; by giving it points of source and destination and demanding the route. Now I want to project the route on an OSM map.

Is there any tools to smooth the result and make sure that the route hasn't lost it's precision during the conversion?

I'm currently trying to check every segment of the route and if both ends lied on the same street, I show the segment.